# Get object created in child thread back in main thread

Tags: python, wxpython

Assume i want to create 500 wxWidget like (some panels , color buttons and text ctrl etc), I have to create all this at single time but this will freeze my main thread, so i put this creation part in child thread and show some gif anim in main thread. But i was not able to get all these wxWidget object those created on my frame in child thread.

Can i get that wxWidgets (created in child thread) back in main thread.
 **simply just consider a case where i have to create children of a frame in child thread and main thread show animation. once child thread finish the all child created in child thread should available in main thread.**

Any help is really appreciable.

I am using python 2.5, wxpython 2.8 on windowsxp.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to send widget objects, if it is, it would be messy. Why don't you save your self the hassle and create the widgets in the main thread, and use a child thread to show a progress dialog or whatever... This will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Actually i have to create so many widgets at a single time if i go for creation of widgets in main thread then it will freeze the GUI.

Comment: Hmm I don't see how it will work, I guess you'll find out soon enough,  consider using the wx.Yield method to periodically update the window, as an alternative to threads.. Iv'e added a basic example to my answer

Comment: @ volting great help man, wx.Yeild() really help for me. StackOverflow really Rock's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pubsub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/projectsusing.html) which is included with wxpython -- `wx.lib.pubsub`.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482112/how-to-control-call-another-python-script-within-one-python-script-communicate/3483161#3483161) for a basic example of usage for inter-thread comms.

---

For an alternative: *An example of how you could use `wx.Yield` to keep your window updated.*

```
import wx

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title, size=(340,380))
        self.SetMinSize((140,180))

        self.creating_widgets = False

        self.panel = wx.Panel(id=wx.ID_ANY, parent=self)

        self.startButton = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Start')
        self.stopButton = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Stop')
        self.messageBox = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, '', size=(75, 20))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  self.onStart, self.startButton)     
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  self.onStop, self.stopButton)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.startButton, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer.Add(self.stopButton, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer.Add(self.messageBox, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def onStart(self, event):
        self.creating_widgets = True
        count = 0
        self.startButton.Disable()
        while self.creating_widgets:
            count += 1
            #Create your widgets here

            #just for simulations sake...
            wx.MilliSleep(100)
            self.messageBox.SetLabel(str(count))

            #Allow the window to update, 
            #You must call wx.yield() frequently to update your window
            wx.Yield()

    def onStop(self, message):
        self.startButton.Enable()
        self.creating_widgets = False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = GUI(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Actually i just want to create wxWidgets/wxObject into child thread and get back in main thread,PUbsub can use as message listener sender only, i cant get how to use pubsub in my case.

Comment: You broadcast the widget object in the child thread and setup up a listener for this in the main thread

Comment: pubsub can send any `type` you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can send them back over a queue, or this all takes place in one instance of a class, assign the widgets to some known place in the instance for the main thread to pick them up. Signal via semaphore.

Comment: a little more description  can really help me a lot

Comment: A working implementation would be even better, but you need to show a working (or non-working) example of your code and problem.